# SQL query group data by matching id and add new columns for unique values

Tags: sql, oracle

Current dataset:

| USER_ID | FEATURE_ID | FEATURE_ID_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | TRUE |
| 321 | 1 | FALSE |
| 123 | 2 | SomeText |
| 321 | 2 | AnotherOne |
| 123 | 3 | MoreText |
| 321 | 3 | EvenMore |

I want to be able to transform this dataset inside a SQL query to produce something like the following:

| USER_ID | FEATURE_ID_1 | FEATURE_ID_2 | FEATURE_ID_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | TRUE | SomeText | MoreText |
| 321 | FALSE | AnotherOne | EvenMore |

I've looked into using Pivots and Group By functions but can't come up with something effective myself.

Comment: Post the work\query you have done so far so we can help you with it.

Comment: @ChrisAlbert The initial dataset is the result of a select all from the table - I need to write a SQL query which returns something like the second table to be used within a app, but I don't really know where to start. I'm currently developing a cheap way of doing this in the apps logic using C# but ideally a SQL query would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a case statement

here is the fiddle  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=025750c52c92080b72b34688a60ba609

```
select user_id, 
max(case feature_id when 1 then feature_id_value else null end) as Feature_ID_1,
max(case feature_id when 2 then feature_id_value else null end) as Feature_ID_2,
max(case feature_id when 3 then feature_id_value else null end) as Feature_ID_3
 from mytable group by user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
PIVOT (
  MAX(feature_id_value)
  FOR FEATURE_ID IN (
    1 AS feature_id_1,
    2 AS feature_id_2,
    3 AS feature_id_3
  )
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (USER_ID, FEATURE_ID, FEATURE_ID_VALUE) AS
SELECT 123, 1, 'TRUE'       FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 321, 1, 'FALSE'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 123, 2, 'SomeText'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 321, 2, 'AnotherOne' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 123, 3, 'MoreText'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 321, 3, 'EvenMore'   FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | USER_ID | FEATURE_ID_1 | FEATURE_ID_2 | FEATURE_ID_3 |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 123 | TRUE | SomeText | MoreText |
> | 321 | FALSE | AnotherOne | EvenMore |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=e9ff2220d3742f887ce216ed9a799b65)*